# Rename multiple files according to the given situation in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have several files like the following:

```
fluxes_30.880_77.040
fluxes_30.880_77.050
fluxes_30.900_77.020
```

Here the numerical values are latitude and longitude.

I need to change the name of all the files in the form:

```
fluxes_30.88_77.04
fluxes_30.88_77.05
fluxes_30.90_77.02
```

Simply, I need the latitude and longitude values in two digits, How to rename all these in command prompt?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Comment: Are you sure that the files each have 3 digit extensions, or have you failed to provide that information in your request?

Comment: Just a (somewhat pedantic) comment. Try to keep the descriptions as simple and clear as possible. The fact that the two numbers are the latitude and longitude is not useful at all. Also, you really want not to need the values _in two digits_. What happen if a file already have two digits? Or one? You just need to _remove the last character from the second and third parts_... On the other hand, the question title is unclear. "according to the given situation" say nothing about your problem... These points may help to write a clearer question when you have a really complicated one.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D fluxes_*') do (
   set "lat=%%a"
   set "long=%%b"
   ren "fluxes_%%a_%%b" "fluxes_!lat:~0,-1!_!long:~0,-1!"
)
```

I don't think this simple code needs further explanations...